# Restricting area awk file

Tags: awk

How to restricted area in file? Say work from row after row that is $2 == end ?

Input file

```
jfk
kdlg
ldlg
ghf
c end 
45 56 56 88
45 55 66 44
44 88 55 10
```

I would like to print numbers in column $1 and $2 that started from row under row `c end`.

Expected output

```
45 56
45 55
44 88
```

Thank you

Comment: Please do mention your efforts which you have put to solve this problem in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk

```
 awk ' /end/ || x==1 { if(x==1) print $1,$2 ; x=1 } '
```

with Inputs

```
$ cat elisabeth.txt
jfk
kdlg
ldlg
ghf
c end
45 56 56 88
45 55 66 44
44 88 55 10

$ awk ' /end/ || x==1 { if(x==1) print $1,$2 ; x=1 } ' elisabeth.txt
45 56
45 55
44 88

$
```

much shorter as suggested by karakfa

```
awk ' /end/ || x { if(x) print $1,$2 ; x=1 } ' elisabeth.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: you can change `x==1` to just `x`

Comment: You're testing `x` twice and setting `x` when it's already set, it's not worth duplicating code for the sake of brevity if that's what you have in mind

Comment: Your approach would also fail if, say, the word `bend` (or any other string that contained `end`) appeared anywhere above the `c end` line.

Comment: @EdMorton..the OP had not explained on the edge cases.. all of our answers will fail in some corner case..

Comment: @EdMorton..assuming the best case i.e "end" could be a word, then ````perl -lane ' print "$F[0] $F[1]" if $x==1; $x=1 if /\bend\b/ ' elisabeth.txt```` would be more robust

Comment: The OP stated she wanted to print the rows following `$2 == end` - given how clear and specific that is and how little we know about the text on the lines before that, IMHO we should just believe her that that's what she wants and not not try to guess at something else that might work instead. wrt all scripts having edge cases - sure but there's clearly garbage text above the line the OP cares about so we shouldn't make any assumptions about what that does or doesn't contain other than that it won't contain a line where $2 is `end`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{flag=""} /end/{flag=1;next} !/end/ && /[a-zA-Z]+/{flag=""} flag{print $2}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
$ awk 'f{print $1, $2} $2=="end"{f=1}' file
45 56
45 55
44 88
```

It's an extremely common awk idiom, not sure why that's not the first answer you got!

Comment: the condition you're testing to turn it off is just a wild guess though - the OP hasn't told us anything to suggest you should stop printing at all, never mind when letters appear in the input without the string `end` also being present. I mean, why stop printing if `bumper` appears in the input but not if `fender` appears? I actually strongly suspect the OP just wants to print from the line after `end` to the end of the file as shown in the question.